# how can i draw a border between DropdownMenuItems in jet pack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android

how can i draw a border between DropdownMenuItems in jet pack compose?

I want to draw a bottom border or a border between the diferent items in a DropDownMenu in jetpack compose in my Topbar Menu.

I try to do this with de modifier = Modifier.border() but i can't.

Comment: you can add a Divider()

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Material Design 2, check out the [`Divider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#Divider(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp)) Composable:

```
DropDownMenuItem(/* ... */)
Divider(startIndent = 8.dp, thickness = 1.dp, color = Color.Black)
DropDownMenuItem(/* ... */)
```

If you are using Material Design 3, check out the [`HorizontalDivider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#HorizontalDivider(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color)) Composable:

```
DropDownMenuItem(/* ... */)
HorizontalDivider()
DropDownMenuItem(/* ... */)
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know this components. And i find a web very interesting about the components of material3.
https://m3.material.io/components